# Layout UITextField regardless of clear button X

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield, uikit

I need to horizontally center layout a `UITextField`, however, since the clear button is part of it, the (text entry portion of) text field doesn't look centered - the clear button isn't always visible but it is taken into account when laying out.

[image: demo of the problem]

In the image above, the `UITextField` is horizontally centered, however, without the clear button (X on the right) and with only search text, it doesn't look like centered.

A way I can think of, is to subclass `UITextField` and provide `alignmentRectInsets`, for inset on the right I would use `clearButtonRect(forBounds:)` to get the size of clear button, whose `width` will be the right inset for `alignmentRectInsets`.

Question:

1. Apple's doc specifically mentions that one should not call `clearButtonRect(forBounds:)` directly, so I'm feeling a bit nervous for doing it; However, from the doc it feels like Apple's intention is to let people not changing the rect, and in my case I'm just getting its size, I guess it's fine?
2. Is there any better way of achieving this? I know I can tweak `edgeInsets`, or give the text field a `leftView`, to make the text field looking centered; But they all need some hardcoded assumption for the size of the clear button.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use stack view to manage this. In the stackView keep both UITextField and the button and hide the button whenever you don't want, stackView will automatically take care of the alignment.

Comment: @vivekDas Thanks for the reply but I'm talking about the clearButton - something that `UITextField` has as subview, not a button that I added.

Comment: Your question not clear, can you add the image of your layout with the button?

Comment: @vivekDas Image added

Answer (score 0):

You can make the UITextField Alignment settings as middle then it will work. Check the below image

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, the text is centered within the text field but the clear button still makes the text field not centered in regard to the container of text field.

Comment: Yes if your clear button will be visible it will take alignment by considering the button width, but once the button is hidden text will be centered.

Comment: Yes what I want is just when the clear button's visible, it should be ignored in term of auto-layout.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can control over here.It may helps to you.Thank you.